# How to import specific parts of the HTML file to WDS?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I want to import the following part (a) of the following HTML files (b) to WDS.

(a) `<meta content="https://qiita.com/xxx/yyy/zzz" property="og:url" />`

I created the following WDS configuration file (c) with the following reference, applied it to the environment, and imported the following HTML files (b).

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/custom-config.html#keep_content

But I could find the part (a), neither in the result of "View data schema", nor the result of "Test your configuration on a document " API (see below).

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/curl.html?curl#test-your-configuration-on-a-document-api

So I have 3 following questions (1)(2)(3).

1. Would you tell me the correct way to make the configuration file if
   the following one (c) is wrong?
2. Where does the part (a) appear in the result of "View data
   schema" if the following configuration file (c) is correct? (Added
   as part of extracted_metadata? Is the parameter name is og: url?)
3. Is the part (a) imported for each divided document if the
   attached configuration file (c) is correct?

(b) HTML Files:

- https://qiita.com/ishida330/items/5afa235ac6a0461f7e5a
- https://qiita.com/ishida330/items/f7cc6d2ea0439fa67b10
- https://qiita.com/ishida330/items/b823d7c5b55806f04242
- https://qiita.com/sukusuku_watson_editorial_room/items/981a4383f9defc5db6f5
- https://qiita.com/sukusuku_watson_editorial_room/items/d8407c938af47bc5ac44

(c) WDS Configuration file:

```html
{
  "configuration_id": "cbcec10a-f241-4fb5-a86d-15e1e732495d",
  "name": "HTML_conf_0914_2",
  "description": null,
  "created": "2018-08-03T00:08:52.320Z",
  "updated": "2018-08-13T01:42:20.763Z",
  "conversions": {
    "pdf": {
      "heading": {
        "fonts": [
          {
            "level": 1,
            "min_size": 24,
            "max_size": 80
          },
          {
            "level": 2,
            "min_size": 18,
            "max_size": 24,
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
          },
          {
            "level": 2,
            "min_size": 18,
            "max_size": 24,
            "bold": true
          },
          {
            "level": 3,
            "min_size": 13,
            "max_size": 18,
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
          },
          {
            "level": 3,
            "min_size": 13,
            "max_size": 18,
            "bold": true
          },
          {
            "level": 4,
            "min_size": 11,
            "max_size": 13,
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "word": {
      "heading": {
        "fonts": [
          {
            "level": 1,
            "min_size": 24,
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
          },
          {
            "level": 2,
            "min_size": 18,
            "max_size": 23,
            "bold": true,
            "italic": false
          },
          {
            "level": 3,
            "min_size": 14,
            "max_size": 17,
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
          },
          {
            "level": 4,
            "min_size": 13,
            "max_size": 13,
            "bold": true,
            "italic": false
          }
        ],
        "styles": [
          {
            "level": 1,
            "names": [
              "pullout heading",
              "pulloutheading",
              "header"
            ]
          },
          {
            "level": 2,
            "names": [
              "subtitle"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "html": {
      "exclude_tags_completely": [
        "script",
        "sup"
      ],
      "exclude_tags_keep_content": [
        "font",
        "em",
        "span"
      ],
      "exclude_content": {
        "xpaths": [
          "//meta[@name]",
          "//meta[@property!='og:url']"
        ]
      },
      "keep_content": {
        "xpaths": [
        ]
      },
      "exclude_tag_attributes": [
        "EVENT_ACTIONS"
      ]
    },
    "json_normalizations": [],
    "segment": {
      "enabled": true,
      "selector_tags": [
        "h1",
        "h2",
        "h3"
      ]
    }
  },
  "enrichments": [
    {
      "enrichment": "natural_language_understanding",
      "source_field": "text",
      "destination_field": "enriched_text",
      "options": {
        "features": {
          "keywords": {},
          "entities": {
            "sentiment": true,
            "emotion": false,
            "limit": 50
          },
          "sentiment": {
            "document": true
          },
          "categories": {},
          "relations": {},
          "concepts": {
            "limit": 8
          },
          "semantic_roles": {}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "normalizations": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the Watson Discovery service extracts only the following three metadata fields from the HTML `<head>` section: **publicationdate**, **author** and **title**.

They are expected to be in your HTML file as in the following example:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <meta name="author" content="Lulu">
   <meta name="publicationdate" content="2015-12-04">
   <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
 <body>
  content of the document
 </body>
</html>
```

Once those three fields are extracted during the ingestion process, they can be queried under the `extracted_metadata` section. The following shows and example of where in the query result those fields would be found:

```
{
    "extracted_metadata": {
        "publicationdate": "2015-12-04",
        "title": "Title of the document",
        "author": "Lulu",
        "filename": "example.html",
        "file_type": "html",
        "sha1": "256f2c4161a1b13528513a3d4abdf00b6ac80054"
    },
    "html": "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><html> ...", 
    "text": "content of the document",
}
```

Unfortunately, extracting other types of metadata fields from the HTML `<head>` section is currently not supported.

There is an alternative way though to ingest custom fields by passing in a metadata part in your POST request. Using `curl`, you could do it by running a command of the form:

```
curl -u ${WDS_USERNAME}:${WDS_PASSWORD} \
-F "file=@YOUR_FILE.html" \
-F "metadata=@YOUR_METADATA.json" \
-X POST "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/documents?version=2018-03-05"
```

See the `metadata` parameter in the documentation at: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/curl.html?curl#add-document